# How to send auth token from local storage to the backend with the request when the user clicks a link

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, local-storage

In my system, when a user signs in, he will receive a JWT token which will be stored in the **local storage**. Also, since he's signed in now, a new link (just a normal anchor link) will show up in the nav bar leading to the dashboard, another will show up somewhere else for signing out, and so on.
Now since the token is stored in the local storage and since the dashboard link is just... well... a link, how can I send the token with the request when the user clicks the link so that I perform the necessary checks on the server?

I can't save the token anywhere else for security reasons (yeah I know this is not entirely secure too, I did the comparisons and decided that it's the best choice for my system), I also can't write API requests for each and every link for obvious reasons! (and other reasons including that I'm using vanilla JS for the front end! Yuck!)

My backend is in node and express if you're interested, but that's not where the problem lies...

Comment: Important !You should write your code along with explanation  otherwise, it will be very difficult to answer your query.

Comment: As the user enters correct credentials you need to store a token into client side (Local storage) and redirect your user to protected route . As the user is redirecting to protected route then you will need to send a post request with your token(which is stored in local storage) to your Api. Api will verify that token if it is invalid then you need to redirect to user to home page otherwise you can keep your user on current page.

Comment: I hope this will help you!

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal you're totally right, but I think for my case, maybe not. Because the answer is simply a "how to" question. "how to send data from local storage to the server when a user clicks a link of another page in the website?" See? There's no code unfortunately...

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal thanks for your help. However I know this method but it's kinda ugly to write an api request for each link (I said that in the question post), so I was asking if there's a better/neater way...

Comment: Are you using React.js or node and Express only.

Comment: For the backend, it's just Node and Express. The front is vanilla JS. @GulshanAggarwal

Comment: If you were using React then I would have answered you with proper code but yeah best of the luck!

Comment: Yeah I know how to do it with React or Vue, I'm unfortunately required to do it with pure JS, thanks anyway for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in cookies:

```
document.cookie = 'token=<token_here>'
```

it is more secure!

[Learn more](https://dev.to/iggredible/cookies-vs-local-storage-vs-session-storage-3gp3)

To pass a token to backend use headers ('Authorization' header) or cookies. Both works.

To perform it with link you have to prevent default link behavior and make ajax call to backend with 'Authorization' header or cookie.

Comment: Provided you have marked the appropriate flags for the cookie...

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee, doesnt matter . you can get any on the backend.